# Store value in join table with composite primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have table `Offer` , `Area` , since one offer can have multiple areas i also have `OfferArea`

```
Offer{
   id  bigserial,
   client_id  bigserial,
   text varchar(500)
} 


Area{
   id bigserial,
   name varchar(50)
}

offer_area{
   offer_id bigserial // pk
   area_id  bigserial // pk
}
```

As you can see `OfferArea` has composite primary key.

I am using JPA:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class OfferAreaPk implements Serializable {
    private long offerId;
    private long areaId;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "offer_area")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OfferAreaEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private OfferAreaPk offerAreaPk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("offerId")
    private OfferEntity offer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("areaId")
    private AreaEntity area;
}
```

Now in my Offer entity i have this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer")
private List<OfferAreaEntity> locations;
```

And in Area entity i have this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "area")
private List<OfferAreaEntity> specializations;
```

But how do i save it to db?

If i do:

```
 OfferEntity offerEntity= offerRepository.save(offerEntity);
AreaEntity areaEntity = areaEntityRepository.findById(areaId);
OfferAreaEntity offerAreaEntity = new OfferAreaEntity();
offerAreaEntity.setOffer(offerEntity);
offerAreaEntity.setArea(areaEntity );
offerAreaRepository.save(offerAreaEntity)
```

I receive error:

```
"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [java.lang.Long]: 'OfferAreaPk.areaId' (setter)"
```

If i try to save it as:

```
OfferEntity offerEntity = new OfferEntity();
AreaEntity areaEntity = areaEntityRepository.findById(areaId);
// other attributes
 OfferAreaEntity offerAreaEntity = new OfferAreaEntity();
 offerAreaEntity.setOffer(offerEntity);
 offerAreaEntity.setArea(areaEntity );
offerEntity.setLocations(Arrays.asList(offerAreaEntity));
offerRepository.save(offerEntity);
```

Nothing is saved in OfferArea tabl.

How do i save the data? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

No need below field in the joining table because offer and area IDs are already unique in the table.

```
@EmbeddedId
private OfferAreaPk offerAreaPk;
```

So try (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) with all mapping annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer_area")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OfferAreaEntity {
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    @MapsId("offerId")
    private OfferEntity offer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    @MapsId("areaId")
    private AreaEntity area;
}
```

[jpa-cascade-types](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)

Comment: this does not work

Comment: If you save offer entity this should be added in that entity  or  you save area entity mapping should be added area class

Comment: i did and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

There were several similar bugs lately identified in Hibernate which the team tries to solve in next incremental releases.

[This bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17290) might be relevant with the case here.

Try to upgrade your dependencies for hibernate with the last incremental build available and check again since there are many hot fixes provided.